# Segmentation Fault while accessing 2-dimensional vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to access a specific position of a 2-dimensional vector. I declared the vector and initialized it, and on printing it out, the vector seems properly declared. Now, when I try to access the vector from an if statement in a class function, I get a segmentation fault.

```
class cache{
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    v.resize(5);
    for(z = 0; z < v.size(); z++){
        v[z].resize(5);
    }
    for(x = 0; x < v.size(); x++){
        for(y = 0; y < v[x].size(); y++){
            v[x][y]=5;
        }
    }

    for(x = 0; x < v.size(); x++){
        for(y = 0; y < v[x].size(); y++){
            cout<<v[x][y]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    int readCache(int a){
        int value = a>>15;
        int index = a % (unsigned long)pow(2,15);
        // Do I not try to access using the size?
        for(x = 0; x < v.size(); x++){
            cout<<v[x][index]<<endl;
            // Or do I use this alternate line?
            // cout<<v[index][x]<<endl;
        }        
    }
};
```

I can't find a proper error message either.

The vector's sizes change depending on the parameters passed to it.

For now, its a 1x2048 vector.

Comment: Change this: `cout<<v[x][index]<<endl;` to this: `cout<<v[x].at(index)<<endl;` -- Now what error do you get?  More than likely, you will now get an `out_of_range` exception thrown and not a seg fault.  Second, do not use `pow` to compute integer powers.  It is a floating point function, thus can be inaccurate.

Comment: If `Cache` is supposed to be a `class`, that's not the way to declare it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you're right. I got an out_of_range exception. I'm not sure I understand vectors correctly. Also, I will change up the pow

Answer (score 0):

Simple out of bound access. You have a 5x5 matrices, but you are trying to get an element outside:

```
    int value = a>>15;
    int index = a % (unsigned long)pow(2,15); // This is also very not efficient
```

The index is most definitely wrong.

Comment: I don't get how I have a 5x5 matrix? I just initialized them all to 5, instead of zero.

Comment: `v.resize(5);` you resize your vector to have a size of 5.

Comment: @RahulRamachandran Interesting. Could you please edit your question stating what the dimensions of that matrix are supposed to be and what that constant 2^15 (=32768) is supposed to stand for?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2: Segmentation Faults appear to be fixed.**

Since this is a homework question, I am unable to post the complete online for fear of plagiarism issues. 
However, the readCache function essentially checks if the address value is present in the nested vector. Now, it seems you cannot directly compare like

```
vec[a][b] = value;
```

It worked when I assigned the value at the desired position to a temporary variable and then compared to the given value. Like this:

```
int temp = vec[a][b];
if(temp == value){
    // do something
}
```

**EDIT: This hasn't worked yet.**

@PaulMcKenzie's comment about accessing vectors helped me get rid of segmentation faults and I started running into out_of_range errors as they predicted.

Then, in the readCache function, I was passing a 32-bit bitset to access a cache. But I don't actually need to access the data byte in a cache block, so the modulus had three extra bits which I didn't need. The range of the modulus function is 0 to (value - 1), so at some point it would exceed the size of the vector.

It is a homework problem.